# Multilingual Python script

Tags: python, json, xml, multilingual

I recently created a Python script and am now considering making it multilingual.

However, I already have all the text written in English and all in that particular script.

So I didn't write down the sentences in any external file and apply variables, but wrote the sentences right into the script.

Now the question: How can I translate the script for another language?

Do I have to replace all the existing sentences with variables? Or is there an API for this?

If I have to replace the sentences with variables, should I use JSON or xml as external language file?

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#internationalizing-your-programs-and-modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different libraries to handle translations of software/scripts, which is called internationalization (i18n). Depending on the library common formats are JSON, gettext, YAML or XML. As an example there is https://pypi.org/project/python-i18n/.

Yes, you basically import the translation function of an i18n-library and provide your text as a parameter. If you also have variables, insert them properly in your text to place them somewhere different depending on the grammar of the language.